# jQueryrotate speed is too slow despite changing the duration setting

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, rotation

I am using the jqueryrotate plugin and I'm having problems getting the image to rotate as fast as I want to. I've reduced the duration down to 1 and even 0.01 but it doesn't seem to make much difference. I want the animation to occur much quicker. Am I missing something, I can't find any advice in the documentation about this?

```
$("#sanalista_words").hide();
$("#sanalista>H2").click(function() {
    if($("#sanalista_words").is(":visible")) {
        $("#sanalista_words").slideUp("slow");
        $("#sl_graph_arrow").rotate({
            duration: 1,
            angle: 180,
            animateTo:1
      });
    }
    else {
        $("#sanalista_words").slideDown("slow");
        $("#sl_graph_arrow").rotate({
            duration: 1,
            angle: 0,
            animateTo:180
      });

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to animate in 1ms ???   duration value is in ms it that duration:1 in fact means  0.001s so changing that value to duration:0.001 (so into 0.00001s) you wont see difference at all i guess

Comment: In that case there must be something wrong somewhere, because my animation takes over a second to complete the full animation. I've just put together a jsFiddle and it seems to work perfectly in that, I can get it to run as fast as I like.